# Access specific dict value in Python

Tags: python

I have a dict object structured in this way:

```
{'snapshots': [{'snapshot': 'test_2018.11.19', 'uuid': 'Lv1C02wIRYGIljr3S16eIQ', 'version_id': 5060699, 'version': '5.6.6', 'indices': ['cribiscom_x_mydocs_entries_201712'], 'state': 'SUCCESS', 'start_time': '2018-11-19T16:57:44.014Z', 'start_time_in_millis': 1542646664014, 'end_time': '2018-11-19T16:57:46.380Z', 'end_time_in_millis': 1542646666380, 'duration_in_millis': 2366, 'failures': [], 'shards': {'total': 3, 'failed':
0, 'successful': 3}}]}
```

I would like to get the value of ket *state* but I'm not really understanding how to do that since *'napshots* is a dict and then there is a composed object.
can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: The value of the key `'snapshots'` is *not* a `dict`, it is a `list`. One that seems sort of useless, since it only has one value... (which is a dict)

Comment: dict['snapshots'][0]['state']

Comment: thank you guys. my fault was due to the type of the first element in snapshots. sorry

Answer (score 0):

This is just a matter of accessing values from a dictionary. You can do it like this:

```
mydict = {'snapshots': [{'snapshot': 'test_2018.11.19', 'uuid':'Lv1C02wIRYGIljr3S16eIQ', 'version_id': 5060699, 'version': '5.6.6', 'indices': ['cribiscom_x_mydocs_entries_201712'], 'state': 'SUCCESS', 'start_time': '2018-11-19T16:57:44.014Z', 'start_time_in_millis': 1542646664014, 'end_time': '2018-11-19T16:57:46.380Z', 'end_time_in_millis': 1542646666380, 'duration_in_millis': 2366, 'failures': [], 'shards': {'total': 3, 'failed': 0, 'successful': 3}}]}
value = mydict['snapshots'][0]['state']
```